# How to run INSERT SPARQL queries from r?

Tags: r, sparql

I would like to run an insert SPARQL query from r using the 'SPARQL' library but it is not working.

Her is the code I used:

```
endpoint <- 'myendpoint'

update <-
  "
  PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
  INSERT DATA {<mypersonid> foaf:hasEmail 'mymail' .}
"

qd <- SPARQL(url = endpoint,
             update = update)
```

Unfortunately it returns only 'Error: ' with any additional details. Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the triple store or SPARQL endpoint you're using? And what the URL? Also, does the SPARQL endpoint provide logs such that you can see more details etc?

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for your comment. Actually, I fixed the issue. I was actually using the wrong endpoint. This is the right endpoint for the POST calls /repositories/{repositoryID}/statements. Thank you!